# SMTP - Email sending fails via proxy (JAVA)

Tags: java, proxy, smtp

I am sending Emails via SMTP (using the mail provider web.de), using this code:

```
    package form.controll;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class NotificationControllerTest {

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    NotificationController aNotifi = new NotificationController( "smtp.web.de", "587" );
    aNotifi.sendEmail( "TARGETEMAIL@blabla.de", "SENDERSEMAIL@web.de", "THESENDERSPASSWORD", "New User Registration Notification", "New User has just been registered to blabla" );
  }

}
```

this works just fine, but if I use the same method in a PROXY context, 
I always get the error:

**535 Authentication credentials invalid**

-Why does this happen?
-How to fix the email sending?

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this FAQ answer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy)

> JavaMail does not currently support accessing mail servers through a
>   web proxy server. One of the major reasons for using a proxy server is
>   to allow HTTP requests from within a corporate network to pass through
>   a corporate firewall. The firewall will typically block most access to
>   the Internet, but will allow requests from the proxy server to pass
>   through. In addition, a mail server inside the corporate network will
>   perform a similar function for email, accepting messages via SMTP and
>   forwarding them to their ultimate destination on the Internet, and
>   accepting incoming messages and sending them to the appropriate
>   internal mail server.
>
> If your proxy server supports the SOCKS V4 or V5 protocol
>   (http://www.socks.nec.com/aboutsocks.html, RFC1928) and allows
>   anonymous connections, and you're using JDK 1.5 or newer and JavaMail
>   1.4.5 or newer, you can configure a SOCKS proxy on a per-session, per-protocol basis by setting the "mail.smtp.socks.host" property as
>   described in the javadocs for the com.sun.mail.smtp package. Similar
>   properties exist for the "imap" and "pop3" protocols.
>
> If you're using older versions of the JDK or JavaMail, you can tell
>   the Java runtime to direct all TCP socket connections to the SOCKS
>   server. See the Networking Properties guide for the latest
>   documentation of the socksProxyHost and socksProxyPort properties.
>   These are system-level properties, not JavaMail session properties.
>   They can be set from the command line when the application is invoked,
>   for example: java -DsocksProxyHost=myproxy .... This facility can be
>   used to direct the SMTP, IMAP, and POP3 communication from JavaMail to
>   the SOCKS proxy server. Note that setting these properties directs all
>   TCP sockets to the SOCKS proxy, which may have negative impact on
>   other aspects of your application.
>
> Without such a SOCKS server, if you want to use JavaMail to access
>   mail servers outside the firewall indirectly, you might be able to use
>   a program such as Corkscrew or connect to tunnel TCP connections
>   through an HTTP proxy server. JavaMail does not support direct access
>   through an HTTP proxy web server.